# Convert date to NULL in SQL SEVER

Tags: sql-server

I am interested in converting the dates to null in SQL server. Here is my simple query:

```
SELECT 
ENTERED_DATE as DATE
ENTERED_DATE as NEXT_DATE
FROM SOMETABLE

DATE                          NEXT_DATE
12/1/2010 12:30:00 AM         12/1/2010 12:30:00 AM
12/1/2010 4:00:00 AM           12/1/2010 4:00:00 AM
12/1/2010 9:00:00 AM           12/1/2010 9:00:00 AM
```

I would like my result something like this:

```
 DATE                          NEXT_DATE
 12/1/2010 12:30:00 AM         (null)
 12/1/2010 4:00:00 AM         (null)
 12/1/2010 9:00:00 AM         (null)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT 
ENTERED_DATE as DATE
CONVERT(datetime, NULL) as NEXT_DATE
FROM SOMETABLE
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT ENTERED_DATE as DATE, CAST(NULL AS DATETIME) as NEXT_DATE 
FROM SOMETABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I completely understand the question, can you do this?

SELECT ENTERED_DATE as DATE, NULL as NEXT_DATE FROM SOMETABLE

Comment: Thanks Brian. I would like to force the NEXT_DATE column as date date type, but do not want to display the dates, instead show the dates as null.

Comment: I tried something like CAST(DATE AS NULL) which gives me this error

Comment: @joe, it's probably the 'as DATE' part, date is a keyword, so it should probably be 'as [Date]'